# Practice problems for linear and non linear regression

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I am new to statistics and am developing an interest in learning regression analysis.
To be more precise, can you point me to some online resources where i can find real world data sets and regression models so that I can practice and check if my thought of process is on the right track.

P.S. I am currently using **R** to learn modeling

Comment: On R's [contributed documentation page](http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html) you can find links to pdfs of various books. You might start w/ *Practical Regression and Anova using R* by Julian Faraway. There is also a [faraway package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/faraway/index.html) that you can instal w/ lots of example datasets that are used in the book. Also note that we have resources for learning R listed [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/795/7290) (among other places).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [HSAUR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HSAUR/) , which has R's popular statistical analysis tools and methods described with sample data sets.

NIST's  Statistical Reference Datasets Project [SrRD](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/strd/index.html) is a great resource for reference data sets to test your routines.